# Ionic 3 Navigation on an particular page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Scenario:

I have four components as shown in the image below. The chatbot component has a navController. If I use `this.navCtrl.push(ComponentD);`, the whole page is filled with component D.

[image]

Requirement:

When I use `this.navCtrl.push(ComponentD);` inside the chatbot component, Component D should be pushed to Component C location, rest of the components should not be disappeared.

How can I do that. Any leads would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you executing this code? NavCtrl is automatically injected by angular. And the injector service finds the closest NavCtrl. So it won't behave always in the same manner. This depends on where you are running the code. Could you post the context where you are doing `this.navCtrl.push(ComponentD);`?
Another way would be looking yourself for the right NavCtrl by doing this.app.getActiveNavs()

Comment: @NicolásLonghi Wow, you are great. this.app.getActiveNav() worked. I was smashing my head for two days. Thanks a lot. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: There I post it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you executing this code? NavCtrl is automatically injected by angular. And the injector service finds the closest NavCtrl. So it won't behave always in the same manner. This depends on where you are running the code. Could you post the context where you are doing `this.navCtrl.push(ComponentD);`? Another way would be looking yourself for the right NavCtrl by doing `this.app.getActiveNavs()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your template of the app-component should look like this:

```
<component-a></component-a>
<component-b></component-b>
<ion-nav [root]="component-c" #content></ion-nav>
```

inside the ion-nav component, the other pages are displayed.